# why is my double pendulum programm isn't working in p5js?

Tags: p5.js, pendulum

```
 var angle1 = 45;
 var angle2 = 0;
 var L1 = 200;var L2 = 200;   


 var m1 = 1;    
 var m2 = 1;    

 var angleV1 = 0;

 var angleV2 = 0;

 var g = 1;





 var angleA1 =
((-g * (2 * m1 + m2) * sin(angle1) -
  m2 * g * sin(angle1 - angle2) -
  2 *
    sin(angle1 - angle2) *
    m2 *
    (angleV2 * angleV2 * L2 +
      angleV1 * angleV1 * L1 * cos(angle1 - angle2))) /
  L1) *
(2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * angle1 - 2 * angle2));
```

var angleA2 =
((2 *
sin(angle1 - angle2) *
(angleV1 * angleV1 * L1 * (m1 + m2) +
g * (m1 + m2) * cos(angle1) +
angle2 * angle2 * L2 * m2 * cos(angle1 - angle2))) /
L2) *
(2 * m1 + m2 - m2 * cos(2 * angle1 - 2 * angle2));

```
angleV1 += angleA1;
angle1 += angleV1;

angleV2 += angleA2;

angle2 += angleV2;



var x1 = sin(angle1) * L1;

var y1 = cos(angle1) * L1;



var x2 = x1 + sin(angle2) * L2;
var y2 = y1 + cos(angle2) * L2;

line(0, 0, x1, y1);

line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Comment: Please provide more details and a [mcve]. What isn't working exactly? Is there an error? What are you expecting to happen? What efforts have you made to debug the code so far? Thanks.

Comment: @bonaalexander The code snippet you shared is missing p5.js `setup()` / `draw()` and it's ambiguous which variables should be defined once at the start of the program and which should be updated continuously. I recommend checking out [Cooding Train's Double Pendulum video and p5.js code](https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/093-double-pendulum.html) (you can even run it straight in the p5.js web editor). Hopefully with the video and following along what's happening in the code the puzzle pieces will fall into place.